# Insert list of dicts into temporary bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a list of dicts representing many rows I'd like to insert into a temporary bigquery table and then merge that temp table with one of my existing tables. I should also note that the dicts have the table columns as their keys.

My list of dicts looks like this:

```
[{'mmsi': '256718000', 'callsign': '9HA3989', 'imo_lr_ihs_no': '1006532', 'name_of_ship': 'SEAHORSE', 'ship_type': 'Yacht', 'gt': '610', 'group_owner': 'Taracan Investments SA', 'technical_manager': 'Alpha + Ltd', 'shipmanager': 'Alpha + Ltd', 'registered_owner': 'Seahorse Navigation Ltd', 'operator': 'Alpha + Ltd', 'operator_code': '5733441', 'registered_owner_code': '6396829', 'length': '51.690'}, {'mmsi': '319833000', 'callsign': '9HA5138', 'imo_lr_ihs_no': '1006673', 'name_of_ship': 'SENSES', 'ship_type': 'Yacht', 'gt': '993', 'group_owner': '  Unknown', 'technical_manager': 'YCO SAM', 'shipmanager': 'YCO SAM', 'registered_owner': 'Argo Marine Ltd', 'operator': 'YCO SAM', 'operator_code': '5073856', 'registered_owner_code': '6126096', 'length': '57.000'}]
```

I have the following code which unnests the array:

```
query = f'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS SELECT * FROM UNNEST({all_ship_info})'
print(query)
result = client.query(query)
print('Result', result.result())
```

However I get the error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Braced constructors are not supported at [1:60]
```

I could potentially create a normal table with an expiration and use insert_rows_json method to add to that but I feel there should be a way to do it with the sql above?

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your question and also provide how does your dictionary data look it? I suspect the dictionary data may require some preparation before load to bigquery.

Comment: I added an example of the values.

Comment: Hi, I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852488/how-can-i-write-a-query-to-insert-array-values-from-a-python-dictionary-in-bigqu will be helpful. If you want to write python dictionary to BigQuery, you will have prepare data in json.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the below code to create a temporary table and insert data into the table. You can make changes to schema and input as per your requirement.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import datetime, pytz, random

PROJECT = "project-id"

def get_temp_table(dataset: str, table_name: str = None, project=None) -> bigquery.Table:
    prefix = "temp"
    suffix = random.randint(10000, 99999)
    if not table_name:
        table_name = "resultset"

    temp_table_name = f"{dataset}.{prefix}_{table_name}_{suffix}"
    if project:
        temp_table_name = f"{project}.{temp_table_name}"
    tmp_table_def = bigquery.Table(temp_table_name)
    tmp_table_def.expires = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc) + datetime.timedelta(
        hours=1
    )

    return tmp_table_def

client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT)

tmp_table_def = get_temp_table("april", "sample", project=PROJECT)
tmp_table_def.schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("id", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("full_name", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("age", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED"),
]
tmp_table = client.create_table(tmp_table_def)  # type: bigquery.Table

data = [
    {"id": "c-1234", "full_name": "John Smith", "age": 39},
    {"id": "c-1234", "full_name": "Patricia Smith", "age": 41},
]

errors = client.insert_rows(tmp_table, data)

print(f"Loaded {len(data)} rows into {tmp_table.dataset_id}:{tmp_table.table_id} with {len(errors)} errors")
```

**Output:**
[image]